# I HAVE AN ERROR #1064 in phpmyadmin :-#1064

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

in following code  - MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

```
CREATE trigger aiou AFTER INSERT ON  `user` 
FOR each
ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO login(  'user',  'password' ) 
VALUES (

'new.user_id',  'new.password'
);
```

Comment: You really should post the error message. Just posting your code doesn't quite cut it as far as quality questions go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use single quotes around column identifiers. You need to use ticks or nothing at all.

```
INSERT INTO login(  'user',  'password' )
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO login(  `user`,  `password` )
```